# I try to use intent implicited call remote service with 'bindService' by aidl in sdk 23,but it always back a null object reference

Tags: android, android-intent, service, aidl

I built two project :one is remote service Pro,the other is test remote service Pro.Remote service implement  aidl interface as follows:

```
package com.example.alpha.receiverserrvice.Services;

// Declare any non-default types here with import statements

interface Pay {
    /**
     * Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
     * and return values in AIDL.
     */
    int pay(String username,String password,float money);
}
```

The remote service register in manifeast:

```
<service android:name=".Services.PayService"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.alpha.alipay"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The remote Service code follow as:

```
public class PayService extends Service {
private Mybinder mybinder;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    mybinder=new Mybinder();
    return mybinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

private class Mybinder extends Pay.Stub{

    @Override
    public int pay(String username, String password, float money) throws RemoteException {
        return safePay(username,password,money);
    }
}

private int safePay(String username,String password,float money){
    if("gyq".equals(username)&&"123456".equals(password)){
        if(money>100){
            return 200;
        }
        else return 500;
    }
    else return 404;
}
}
```

And test remote service code in the other project follow as:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Myconn conn;
private Pay payment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent=new Intent("com.example.alpha.alipay");
    intent.setPackage("com.example.alpha.receiverserrvice.Services");
    conn=new Myconn();
    bindService(intent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.pay);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Payfor(view);
        }
    });
}

public void Payfor(View view) {
    try {
        int resultcode= payment.pay("gyq123", "123456", 300.0f);
        if (200==resultcode) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "pay success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (resultcode==404) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (resultcode==500) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Lack of balance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class Myconn implements ServiceConnection{

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        payment=Pay.Stub.asInterface(service);
        Log.d("zhifubao.client", "bind remote servoce success.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
}
```

Finally the error in android studio follow as:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.example.alpha.receiverserrvice.Services.Pay.pay(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, float)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.alpha.testpayservice.MainActivity$override.Payfor(MainActivity.java:47)
        at com.example.alpha.testpayservice.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
        at com.example.alpha.testpayservice.MainActivity.Payfor(MainActivity.java:0)                                                                                  
        at com.example.alpha.testpayservice.MainActivity$1$override.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)                                                                                  
        at com.example.alpha.testpayservice.MainActivity$1$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)                                                                                  
        at com.example.alpha.testpayservice.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:0)                                                                                  
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)                                                                                  
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)                                                                                  
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)                                                                                 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                  
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                  
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)                                                                                  
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                  
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)                                                                                  
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

So when i try to bind remote service to call method it always back me null object reference,I'dont know where is problem,If you can find it ,please tell.Thank you.

Comment: so you are saying that in `Myconn#onServiceConnected`  the `IBinder service` parameter is null?

Comment: @alpha It would be useful if you could link the actual error output as well as the code

Comment: Try to remove this line `intent.setPackage("com.example.alpha.receiverserrvice.Services");`

Comment: @pskink maybe,even the method onbind() in service dose not be excuted.Is that the aidl is not correct?

Comment: In addition, you got `android:permission="string"` in Service's declaration in manifest - it is intentional, or just a copy-pasted part? If you don't define custom permission named `string`, remove this line,

Comment: @Tibrogargan I had add the error in AS

Comment: `Log.d` the return value of `bindService`

Comment: @Vasiliy this line is necessary，because in version 23 ,the as tell me that implicit call need this command.

Comment: and you should use `intent.setPackage("com.example.alpha.receiverserrvice");` i think this is the correct package name

Comment: @Vasiliy yes this line is intentional,if not ,there will be a waring.

Comment: @pskink wow! It work! I'm So happy!Thank you very much!

Comment: @pskink Can you post the answer for this question ? I will choose you as correct answer,and also stop this question.thank you again.

Comment: @Vasiliy you are right,if add this line,i' cant call the remote service,in this question,i made two mistakes,one is set incorrect packname,the other is add this line.Thank you very much!^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your package name is wrong, it should be:

```
intent.setPackage("com.example.alpha.receiverserrvice");
```